# How to create a font file from a base64 encoded font string in java

Tags: java, fonts, truetype

I have a base64 encoded font String

```
String font_data="font/truetype;charset=utf-8;base64,AAEAAAAMAIAAAwBAT1MvMmaobcEAAAFIAAAAVmNtYXCo5nJcAAACgAAAAVJnYXNw//8AAwAAKHQAAAAIZ2x5Zt1rdPEAAARIAAAULGhlYWTx2l1e   ...........  AFwAXQAAAAAAAf//AAI=";
```

Now I want to create a `.ttf`  font file using `java`;

How to do this?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You could probably even load the font without creating a file first by using the class [ByteArrayInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html).

Answer (score 3):

Just decode the base64 part and save it in a file (I'm assuming that part is really a True Type font).

If you're using Java 7:

```
String fontData = "font/truetype;charset=utf-8;base64,QUJDREU= ... ";

fontData = fontData.substring(fontData.indexOf("base64,") + 7);

File ttFile = new File("/path/to/your/file.ttf");
try (FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(ttFile)) {
    byte[] binary = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(fontData);
    output.write(binary);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If you're using Java 6:

```
String fontData = "font/truetype;charset=utf-8;base64,QUJDREU= ... ";

fontData = fontData.substring(fontData.indexOf("base64,") + 7);

File ttFile = new File("/path/to/your/file.ttf");
try {
    FileOutputStream output = null;
    try {
        output = new FileOutputStream(ttFile);
        byte[] binary = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(fontData);
        output.write(binary);
    } finally {
        if(output != null) {
            output.close();
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If you're using an older version, download and add to your classpath [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/download_codec.cgi), and try this:

```
String fontData = "font/truetype;charset=utf-8;base64,QUJDREU= ... ";

fontData = fontData.substring(fontData.indexOf("base64,") + 7);

File ttFile = new File("/path/to/your/file.ttf");
FileOutputStream output = null;
try {
    try {
        output = new FileOutputStream(ttFile);
        byte[] binary = new org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64().decode(fontData);
        output.write(binary);
    } finally {
        if(output != null) {
            output.close();
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```